# contar dos campos de una tabla en php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

tengo una tabla que se llama **matriculas_2018** y dos campos uno de **cursos** y el otro de **especialidad**.

quiero poner un contador que me diga cuantos alumnos del curso **TERCERO MEDIO** corresponden a la especialidad **ADMINISTRACION** y otro que me haga la misma función pero con la especialidad de **CONTABILIDAD**

espero me puedan ayudar.. gracias